# dynamic object naming in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Not sure of the best way to phrase this question. Here goes.

I have a typescript class containing static objects:

```
export class  MonkeyParams {
  constructor() {}

  static idParam : interfaces.ParameterObject = {
    name: "id",
    in: "path",
    type: "string",
    enum: ["6/8 digit deviceId", "all"],
    description: "device Id - Unique 6 to 8 digit hexadecimal number from QR code on device enclosure",
    required: true
  };

  static fromTimeParam : interfaces.ParameterObject = {
    name: "fromTime",
    in: "query",
    type: "integer",
    format:"int32",
    description: "Unix Timestamp in seconds: the start time for the period of interest",
    required: true
  };
  ...
```

Inside another file I want to refer to the values of the 'required' property in these objects. The difficulty is that the objects are being used to dynamically create other objects. In this code, what I want to do is propogate the 'required' property into the new object when the object relates to that parameter. But I can't figure out the grammar to make it work... Unlike where the object key is generated dynamically with a square bracket it doesn't see to be possible to do a similar thing with the static class property. You get an error like this:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof MonkeyParams'.   No index
> signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof
> MonkeyParams'.ts(7053)

Here's the code for that bit:

```
        queryList.forEach(query => {
          let methodPropName = 'method.request.querystring.' + query;
          let integrationPropName = 'integration.request.querystring.' + query;

          // this._methodOptions.requestParameters[methodPropName]      = true;              // using computed property names!
          let key = `${query}Param`;
          this._methodOptions.requestParameters[methodPropName] = MonkeyParams[key].required;
          this._lambdaOptions.requestParameters[integrationPropName] = methodPropName;
        });
```

The key lines are where I've commented out where it sets true. And I'm trying to replace it with the value from the required property coming from the static object in the MonkeyParams class.

Answer (score 0):

I added Params enum to define the key's type. So you must check `queryList` contains all valid params.

```
// add enum here <---
enum Params {
  'idParam' = 'idParam', 'fromTimeParam' = 'fromTimeParam'
}

queryList.forEach(query => {
  const methodPropName = 'method.request.querystring.' + query;
  const integrationPropName = 'integration.request.querystring.' + query;

  // this._methodOptions.requestParameters[methodPropName]      = true;              // using computed property names!
  const key: Params = `${query}Param` as Params; <---
  this._methodOptions.requestParameters[methodPropName] = MonkeyParams[key].required;
  this._lambdaOptions.requestParameters[integrationPropName] = methodPropName;
});
```